# SQL grouping by distinct values in a multi-value string column

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift

(I want to perform a group-by based on the distinct values in a string column that has multiple values

The said column has a list of strings in a standard format separated by commas. The potential values are only `a,b,c,d`.

For example the column `collection` (type: String) contains:

```
Row 1: ["a","b"]
Row 2: ["b","c"]
Row 3: ["b","c","a"]
Row 4: ["d"]`
```

The expected output is a count of unique values:

```
collection | count
a | 2
b | 3
c | 2
d | 1
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using and describe the data type of `collection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all the below i used this table:

```
create table tmp (
 id INT auto_increment,
 test VARCHAR(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into tmp (test) values 
    ("a,b"),
    ("b,c"),
    ("b,c,a"),
    ("d")
;
```

If the possible values are only `a,b,c,d` you can try one of this:
Tke note that this will only works if you have not so similar values like `test` and `test_new`, because then the `test` would be joined also with all `test_new` rows and the count would not match

```sql
select collection, COUNT(*) as count from tmp JOIN (
    select CONCAT("%", tb.collection, "%") as like_collection, collection from (
        select "a" COLLATE utf8_general_ci as collection
        union select "b" COLLATE utf8_general_ci as collection
        union select "c" COLLATE utf8_general_ci as collection
        union select "d" COLLATE utf8_general_ci as collection
    ) tb
) tb1 
ON tmp.test LIKE tb1.like_collection
GROUP BY tb1.collection;
```

Which will give you the result you want

```
collection | count
    a      |   2
    b      |   3
    c      |   2
    d      |   1
```

or you can try this one

```sql
SELECT 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmp WHERE test LIKE '%a%') as a_count,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmp WHERE test LIKE '%b%') as b_count,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmp WHERE test LIKE '%c%') as c_count,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmp WHERE test LIKE '%d%') as d_count
;
```

The result would be like this

```
a_count | b_count | c_count | d_count
2       |    3    |   2     |   1
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to first *explode* the collection column into separate rows (like a `flatMap` operation). In redshift the only way to *generate* new rows is to `JOIN` - so let's `CROSS JOIN` your input table with a static table having consecutive numbers, and take only ones having `id` less or equal to number of elements in the collection. Then we'll use `split_part` function to read the item at correct index. Once we have the exploaded table, we'll do a simple `GROUP BY`.

If your items are stored as JSON array strings (`'["a", "b", "c"]'`) then you can use `JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH` and `JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT` instead of `REGEXP_COUNT` and `SPLIT_PART` respectively.

```
with 
    index as (
        select 1 as i 
        union all select 2 
        union all select 3 
        union all select 4 -- could be substituted with 'select row_number() over () as i from arbitrary_table limit 4'
    ), 
    agg as (
        select 'a,b' as collection
         union all select 'b,c'
         union all select 'b,c,a'
         union all select 'd'
    )
    select 
        split_part(collection, ',', i) as item,
        count(*)
    from index,agg
    where regexp_count(agg.collection, ',') + 1 >= index.i -- only get rows where number of items matches
    group by 1
```